# Are minions able to capture points?

Tags: league-of-legends

In Dominion mode, are friendly minions able to capture points on their own? I've seen them go up to towers, and fire something at the capture point that *slowly* started to capture the point.

So, are they able to literally capture a point, or can they only assist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they can capture points. However, because the point shoots at them, you need a  critical mass of minions (probably 15 or more) for it to actually happen before they all die. Promoted minions used to be useful for this. (its been a while since I played)

Comment: It is probably somewhat difficult to stack that many minions in Dominion, but you could probably get away with only killing the enemy caster minions to get a decent sized stack. However the emphasis of Dominion is in fast paced play so there is no real way to stack minions that would be strategically superior to just walking up to the point and taking it.